# Change button value on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button, onclick

I want to be able to change the value of the button from "Submit" to "Submitted" when ajax succeeds.

```
success: function () {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Message recieved!",
      text: "We will get back to you soon.",
      icon: "success",
    }); 
    $("#contactFormButton").click(function(){
      // disabling the button
      $(this).prop("disabled",true);
      // Adding a mail submitted icon 
      $(this).html(
        'Submitted! <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-envelope-check-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M.05 3.555A2 2 0 0 1 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 1 1.95 1.555L8 8.414.05 3.555ZM0 4.697v7.104l5.803-3.558L0 4.697ZM6.761 8.83l-6.57 4.026A2 2 0 0 0 2 14h6.256A4.493 4.493 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.49 4.49 0 0 1 1.606-3.446l-.367-.225L8 9.586l-1.239-.757ZM16 4.697v4.974A4.491 4.491 0 0 0 12.5 8a4.49 4.49 0 0 0-1.965.45l-.338-.207L16 4.697Z"/><path d="M16 12.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 1-7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 7 0Zm-1.993-1.679a.5.5 0 0 0-.686.172l-1.17 1.95-.547-.547a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708l.774.773a.75.75 0 0 0 1.174-.144l1.335-2.226a.5.5 0 0 0-.172-.686Z"/></svg>'
      );
    });
}
```

This works np. But I want it to work when the button is not clicked...In other words the button value "submit" should get changed to "Submitted" when ajax succeeds without the need to click the button again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Why can't you just add an ID to the button and do something like `$('#ID').html('Submitted')`

Comment: Yep did just that.
It doesnt work rn but i made a sample file and it works there so yea thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering,
I couldn't get  `$('#ID').html('Submitted')` to work.

Instead the following worked np:

```
success: function () {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Message recieved!",
      text: "We will get back to you soon.",
      icon: "success",
    }); 
    //change button text to submitted
    $(document.getElementById('contactFormButton')).html('Submitted! <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-envelope-check-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M.05 3.555A2 2 0 0 1 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 1 1.95 1.555L8 8.414.05 3.555ZM0 4.697v7.104l5.803-3.558L0 4.697ZM6.761 8.83l-6.57 4.026A2 2 0 0 0 2 14h6.256A4.493 4.493 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.49 4.49 0 0 1 1.606-3.446l-.367-.225L8 9.586l-1.239-.757ZM16 4.697v4.974A4.491 4.491 0 0 0 12.5 8a4.49 4.49 0 0 0-1.965.45l-.338-.207L16 4.697Z"/><path d="M16 12.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 1-7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 7 0Zm-1.993-1.679a.5.5 0 0 0-.686.172l-1.17 1.95-.547-.547a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708l.774.773a.75.75 0 0 0 1.174-.144l1.335-2.226a.5.5 0 0 0-.172-.686Z"/></svg>');
    //disable button
    $(document.getElementById('contactFormButton')).prop('disabled',true);
},
```